# Cannot assign value of type 'SignUpViewController' to type '(UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate)?'

Tags: swift

```
@objc func presentPicker(){
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
picker.allowsEditing = true
picker.delegate = self //error
self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


extension SignInViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
func imagePickerController(\_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: \[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any\]) {
if let imageSelected = info\[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage\] as? UIImage {
avatar.image = imageSelected}

        if let imageOriginal = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as?
            UIImage {
            avatar.image = imageOriginal
        }
        
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }

}
```

I think(!) I have copied the tutorial code correctly but get two errors in my `ImagePicker` struct

```
//Error: Cannot assign value of type 'SignUpViewController' to type '(UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate)?'
```

I'm using Xcode 13.

Comment: You are missing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At line

> `picker.delegate = self`

You have assigned `SignUpViewController` object to picker delegate and you have inherited `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` into `SignInViewController` class instead of `SignUpViewController`

replace extension `SignInViewController:` with extension  `SignUpViewController:`